# Why use HTML snippet in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Sometimes, I see code something like this:

```
<asp:ListItem Value="SomeValue">SomeValue</asp:ListItem>

<asp:literal id="SomeId" Runat="server" Text="SomeText"></asp:literal>
```

Why put `asp:` when I can just use `<ListItem>...</ListItem>` ?
What is the benefit of using it?

Comment: In what context does "when I can just use <ListItem>...</ListItem>" come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When a browser requests an HTML file, the server returns the file
- When a browser requests an ASP file, IIS passes the request to the
  ASP engine. The ASP engine reads the ASP file, line by line, and
  executes the scripts in the file. Finally, the ASP file is returned
  to the browser as plain HTML

[What can ASP do for you?](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_intro.asp)